# 3-fold cross-validation using Joaquim's SVM light

Tags: data-mining, classification, svm, document-classification

I need to do a 3-fold cross validation using Joaquim's SVM light. Cross Validation and SVM are new things to me and I don't know if I'm doing it right. What have I done so far? I converted my data in 3 files that I called fold1.txt fold2.txt fold3.txt with my features in this following model:

1 numberofthefeature:1 numberofthefeature:1 ...

And I also did a file called words.txt with my tokens where the number of the lines are my numberofthefeature. Did I do everything right?

So, now I have to do the 3-fold cross-validation, but I don't know how to do it with Joaquim's SVM light. I don't know to make the svm light learn and classify using the three files and choose which ones I'm going to use as a test and a train. Do I have to do a script or a program to do it?

Thanks to everybody

Thiago

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am gonna assume that you are doing text-mining as you are referring to Thorsten Joachims. Anyways, here is a set of tutorial videos on text classification, with x-validation:

http://vancouverdata.blogspot.ca/2010/11/text-analytics-with-rapidminer-part-5.html